# Searching JSON with jQuery by Keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to search JSON specifically by keyword. I've successfully searched by an ID, which in the code below, is "tags". Though, what I want to do is, search within the ID of "tags" but by the keyword of "depreciated". Only the bracketed in JSON that say "depreciated" will be selected. Then the title and uri will be pulled from that and written to the document, like I have in my code.

How might I go about doing a keyword search with my current code? If my logic is hard to understand, please let me know in the comments. Thanks in advance :)

Note: This is exactly the JSON format in which the data will be used.

Here's my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.onload=function(){
  var data = {
         "Feed": [
           {
              "categories":[
              "Depreciated",
              "Test"
              ],
              "content":"",
              "tags":[
              "Depreciated",
              "Test"
              ],
              "title":"Visual Design",
              "uri":"google.com"
            },
            {
               "categories":[
               "Depreciated"
               ],
               "content":"",
               "tags":[
               "Depreciated"
               ],
               "title":"Typography",
               "uri":"google.com"
             }
         ]
      },
      res = JSON.search( data, '//*[tags]' );

  for (var i=0, str=''; i<res.length; i++) {
      str += '<a href="' + res[i].uri + '">Link</a>' + res[i].title + '<br/>';
  }

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted your question, it's an excellent question.

Comment: Thank you! Probably because I'm not a "pro" :P

Comment: You can iterate over your json object and test for whatever you want.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Comment: I see, so essentially I can call the first $key being "tags" and listen for the second, third, and beyond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use jQuery for this. [Try something like this instead](https://jsbin.com/nayozoveye/edit?html,css,js,console,output):

```
function getTitlesByTag(arr, tag) {
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
     return item.tags.includes(tag)
  }).map(function(item) {
    return return {
      title: item.title,
      uri: item.uri
    }
  })
}
```

[`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) has no IE support, so if you're concerned about that you can swap that check out for indexOf like so:

```
function getTitlesByTag(arr, tag) {
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
     return item.tags.includes(tag)
  }).map(function(item) {
    return {
      title: item.title,
      uri: item.uri
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: shadymoses, thank you for the code walk-thru and example. This is helpful! Trying to understand your code and Will's - your method, is it breaking down the JSON into a more understandable array and then it's placed into a function to be accessed?

Comment: Yes. The relevant data you're looking for is an array, so if you can always rely on that structure then you can just point directly to it. Working with arrays is very convenient. You don't have to have a separate function if the code doesn't need to be abstracted.

Answer (score 0):

shadeymoses was faster than me, but essentially you just need `filter()` and `map()`.

```js
var data = {
  "Feed": [{
      "categories": [
        "Depreciated",
        "Test"
      ],
      "content": "",
      "tags": [
        "Depreciated",
        "Test"
      ],
      "title": "Visual Design",
      "uri": "google.com"
    },
    {
      "categories": [
        "Depreciated"
      ],
      "content": "",
      "tags": [
        "Depreciated"
      ],
      "title": "Typography",
      "uri": "google.com"
    }
  ]
};

let results = data.Feed.filter(el => el.tags.includes('Depreciated')).map(el => ({
  uri: el.uri,
  title: el.title
}));

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks Will! This is very helpful as well. Filters make sense. Just so I understand, a Filter will separate the data into chucks for a variable?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter It iterates over an array and returns a (usually smaller
) array.

Comment: What are your thoughts on a return of null?